# Script gets triggered at bottom of div instead of top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a count up script to be triggered when i reach a specific div, but instead of when it reaches top of the div it starts when it reaches the bottom, why so?

my html:

```
    <div id="status_counter" class="status_bar">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <h2><div class="counter" data-count="33">0</div></h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <h2><div class="counter" data-count="25">0</div></h2>!-

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <h2><div class="counter" data-count="15">0</div></h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="counter-item">
                    <h2><div class="counter" data-count="42">0</div></h2>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my counter.js:

```
var eventFired = false,
    objectPositionTop = $('#status_counter').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {

 var currentPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
 if (currentPosition > objectPositionTop && eventFired === false) {
   eventFired = true;


    $('.counter').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

      $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      },

      {

        duration: 2000,
        easing:'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
          //alert('finished');
        }

      });  



    });   




 }

});
```

Currently: when is scroll down to the status_counter it doesnt trigger my script until i scroll down to the bottom of it.

I would like my Count up script to be triggered as soon as the status_counter div appears on my screen, so when the top/start of status_counter div reaches the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well this should work:

```
var eventFired = false,
    objectPositionTop = $('#status_counter').offset().top,
    objectPositionBottom = objectPositionTop;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var currentPositionBottom = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (currentPositionBottom > objectPositionBottom && eventFired === false) {
        eventFired = true;

        $('.counter').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

            $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing:'linear',
                step: function() {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            }, complete: function() {
                $this.text(this.countNum);         
            }
            });  
        });   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the bottom position of the element vs the bottom position of the window (which is the scrollHeight + the window height):

```
objectPositionTop = $('#status_counter').offset().top;
objectPositionBottom = objectPositionTop + $('#status_counter').height();
```

And inside the `scroll` you can use:

```
var currentPositionBottom = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
if (currentPositionBottom > objectPositionBottom && eventFired === false) {
```

Here is a fork of your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rop0g9gz/1/

Comment: Why bottom of the element? i want it to launch when the top of the element(#status_counter) reaches the bottom of my window aka as soon as it appears on screen to start loading numbers

Comment: You said the current code works for the top of the element. If you want to change it to the bottom of the element - this code is what you are looking for. If that's not the case - update the question.

Comment: No i said it works in the way so it gets triggered at bottom of the div instead of top. At the end of my post i asked what makes it trigger at bottom, because i want to know the bug...

Comment: ok, so it wasn't clear enough. please provide a working example (http://jsfiddle.net for example, or snippets here in stackoverflow) that demonstrates exactly the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rop0g9gz/ but for some reason on jsfiddle the script doesnt work at all now (on jsfiddle that is), but yeah generally i just want my count up script to start counting, as soon as i scroll to the status_counter div

Comment: because you didn't include the jquery script there. now what exactly is the problem? (update the question, explain what is currently happen and what is the problem - what you actually want to happen).

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `div` you want to count when you over it:

```
var exampleDiv = document.getElementById("#YOUR-DIV-ID")
```

and attach it to the `mouseover` event:

```
exampleDiv.addEventListener('mouseover' , your-count-function)
```